# How do I find the index of an item in an array when the array is indexed by an enum type?

Tags: arrays, delphi, enums

In my code I have the following type and array
I get a string that I would like to check if it exist in the array and from its index I need to get a value from TProgramModule

Example: I have the text Job and needs to find that it has the index 3 in array ModuleName then I need to check TProgramModule and get modJobsystem as it is item 3

Hope that explains what I am looking for - any other ways to get the result is also welcome

```
type
  TProgramModule = (
                    modBlank,
                    modMeter,
                    modFinance,
                    modJobsystem,
                    modTimesheet,
                    modTaskmanagement,
                    modHomeContents,
                    modDiary,
                    modCases,
                    modDocuments,
                    modContacts
                   );

const
  ModuleName: array[TProgramModule] of string = (
                                                  'Blank',
                                                  'Måleraflæsning',
                                                  'Konti',
                                                  'Job',
                                                  'Timesedler',
                                                  'Opgaver',
                                                  'Indbo',
                                                  'Dagbog',
                                                  'Sagsstyring',
                                                  'Dokumentstyring',
                                                  'Kontaktpersoner'
                                                );
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done pretty simply with a loop:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Find: string;
  Module: TProgramModule;
begin
  Find := 'Job';
  for i := Low(ModuleName) to High(ModuleName) do
    if ModuleName[i] = Find then
    begin
      Module := i;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

You should probably turn this into a function that accepts the value to search for as a string and returns the proper `TProgramModule`. The question at that point becomes what the function should return if the string isn't found in `ModuleName`.

```
function FindProgramModule(const Name: string): TProgramModule;
var
  i: TProgramModule;
begin
  for I := Low(ModuleName) to High(ModuleName) do
    if ModuleName[i] = Name then
      Exit(i);    
  Exit(modBlank);  // Not found - return whatever default value here
end;
```

For older versions of Delphi that don't support `Exit()`:

```
function FindProgramModule(const Name: string): TProgramModule;
var
  i: TProgramModule;
begin
  Result := modBlank;   // Whatever default value goes here
  for I := Low(ModuleName) to High(ModuleName) do
    if ModuleName[i] = Name then
    begin
      Result := i;    
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I was thinking about `FindProgramModule(const Name:String;var pm:TProgramModule):Boolean;` but you already beat me :)

Comment: @bummi: :-) I thought about a var param and a Boolean result, but my personal preference would be another element added to `TProgramModule` like `modNone`, so you could use the function result in a `case` statement.

Comment: This is clumsy. Since result is of `Ordinal` type, its possible to use it as loop control variable directly.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: I prefer not doing so. Allocating a loop control var doesn't cost anything, and to me it makes the code easier to read. I wouldn't call it "clumsy"; just not to your preferences. I wouldn't insult your code because you used different formatting style than I prefer.

Comment: It did cost you writing two versions already... One of them with type mismatches.

Comment: @Free: You're right about the type mismatch; fixed (and thanks for pointing it out). The "two versions" didn't cost me anything; one is for older versions of Delphi that don't support Exit with a value. I didn't have to write it at all; I did so as a courtesy, because the poster didn't include any version tags. As I said, it's a preference thing. If you don't agree with my preference, that's fine. I may not agree with your formatting or choice of variable names all the time, either. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it like this:

```
function FindProgramModule(const Name: string): TProgramModule;
begin
  for Result := Low(ModuleName) to High(ModuleName) do
    if ModuleName[Result] = Name then
      Exit;
  Raise EModuleNotFound.CreateFmt(
    'Module not recognised: %s',
    [Name]
  );
end;
```

If you don't want to raise an exception then return a sentinel enum to indicate that the module was not recognised.

Comment: I have been given something to work with in more than one comment
Thanks to everyone for input